# Oracle with XML to Postgres in JSON Converstion

Tags: json, xml, oracle, postgresql

I am trying to migrate Oracle codes to Postgres, at the same time in Oracle we are using XML and in PostgreSQL we are using JSON.
So while migrating I am stuck with few basic points,

like in oracle,

There is a function newDOMDocument:

```
FUNCTION newDOMDocument RETURN domdocument;
```

Now in a procedure which needs to be migrated has variable declared as:

```
doc               DOMDocument;
ndoc              DOMNode;
root_elmt         DOMElement;
```

and in declaration section we have:

```
doc  := newDOMDocument;
nDoc := makeNode(doc);
root_elmt := createElement(doc, 'stm');
```

Could you please help to convert it in JSON in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you migrate to JSON in Oracle?